# How to deploy an application with addon to a war file

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, vaadin, vaadin7

I am using a responsive add-on to my Vaadin project. I complied the widget and I am able to run the project on Eclipse.  The version that I am using is Vaadin 7.1.9 and Eclipse Juno.

Then when I tried to export to a war file and deployed it on Jetty 8 and Jetty 9. I am getting the following errors for each.

In Jetty 8, I am getting back:
I am able to launch jetty but when I tried to access if from the browser I am getting back the following:

```
      Widgetset does not contain implementation for com.vaadin.addon.responsive.Responsive. 
      Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. 
      In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.
```

in Jetty 9, I am getting back:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path: /*
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandle
    r.java:1383)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHa
    ndler.java:1480)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHan
    dler.java:916)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.WebServletAnnotation.apply(WebServletAn
```

Please note: I have another war file which got executed successfully in both Jetty 8 and Jetty 9. Also my project works without that widgetset.

With Jetty 8, I tried recompling the widgets again but I got back same error.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
        <display-name>Demo</display-name>
        <context-param>
            <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
            <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Myrmnui Application</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.demo.main.DemoResponsiveAppServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <description>Vaadin UI class</description>
                <param-name>UI</param-name>
                <param-value>com.demo.main.MainUI</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <description>
                Application widgetset</description>
                <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
                <param-value>com.demo.main.widgetset.DemoWidgetset</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

Please let me know how can I build a war file and deploy along with widget. I used eclipse to export to war file. To make sure that widget files exist, I unziped the war file and they are present. These files are not of zero file size.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a solution which I found: This works for Jetty 8.

In your VaadinServlet custom class, we need to specify widgetset package, see below:

        @WebServlet(value = {"/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, asyncSupported = true)
        @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MainUI.class, widgetset="com.demo.main.widgetset.DemoWidgetset")

Answer (score 0):

The error ...

```
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path: /*`
```

... is telling, as it points to an invalid WAR deployment, where there are multiple servlets all mapping to the same path-spec.  That's not allowed in the Servlet API.

Is it possibly that one of them should be a filter?

Or that some library is bringing in more `@WebServlet(value={"/*"})` entries that are conflicting with yours?

If you setup `DEBUG` logging (or `FINEST` if using `java.util.logging`) against the named logger `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler` you can see some scant detail on what's going on.

However, the error message can be improved, so a bug has been filed to improve it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/424284